# How to activate a pn2222 transistor with very low voltage

Tags: transistors, switches, solid-state-relay

How to activate a  pn2222 transistor with very low voltage  0.15 volts or 150 mV   from a small dc can motor Generator. I would like the Transistor to turn on as soon as the generator starts producing current.  the problem I had is the Power source is running back through the Transistor and spinning the Motor/Generator. I want the Generator to give power to the base of the Transistor to activate some LEDs.  This is a small 6 volt can motor as a wind generator. I also tried a 3A Solid state Relay  but it needs conrtol voltage at least 3 v. Would it be reasonable to try a Ge transistor instead of the Si one .

Thanks

Comment: Some clarification please. Do you know the available current from your generator? Do you understand the problem in turning on this transistor with Vbe = 0.15V (150mV)? What is the power source for the LEDs? You seem to be saying that current is passing from the collector through the base of your NPN transistor into your generator, are you sure about that? It would be very useful if you could show your setup using the built-in schematic editor, or by uploading a picture.

Comment: Schematic. Post a schematic or this is bound to be closed as unclear. But if you post a schematic, I am pretty sure someone will have some helpful suggestions.

Comment: Also, please clarify the voltage. 0.15V = 150mV. 1500mV would be 1.5V. Normally Volts are capital (because Volta was a person) but "milli-" is lower case. So it is "V" or "mV." "MV" would be mega-Volts.

Comment: where does LED power come from in this miser current spec.  The proper solution is a logic level FET

Comment: OK great. I will work on that

Comment: Before I write What I did, witch was obviously wrong.  Can I post what i need? I have a small 6v DC  motor with a propeller.  I would like the motor to generate electricity from the wind and send it to a Transistor or Solid state relay to turn on some Bright LEDs using 2AA batteries.  It is a small wind generator display model.. the motor only generates  .2 volt on my meter so it was not enough to trigger the solid Sate relay of 3v control.

Comment: I would look into using an analog comparator IC instead of a transistor.

Comment: This is clearly a X-Y problem.  You are asking for details of making some imagined implementation work.  Instead, ask about the real problem you are trying to solve, and leave your imagined details, like using a particular transistor, out of it.  Also, it's not clear whether everything needs to be powered from the generator, or if there is external power available and you only want to light a indicator when the generator is running at all.

Comment: If you change the propeller, maybe the motor will spin faster and generate more voltage. It must be spinning very slowly to generate such a low voltage.

Comment: Question,  How can I turn On an LED powered by 2 AA Batteries Switched on from a low voltage .15v from a small Genorator? When the wind blows The small Generator has a propeller and I would like to send a signal to turn on the The LED that is powered by 2AA batteries. The generator Is not powerful enough to light the LED on it's own for this application.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you insist on doing this, then use a comparator powered from the 2AA batteries. You will need to somehow generate a 0.15V reference voltage to use as your switching threshold.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to switch a transistor with only 0.15 Volts. You need more than 0.2 for Ge. I think a smaller area propeller will turn faster and generate a higher voltage.

Comment: I think this answers the question although it doesn't solve the problem. As @rioraxe said, an analog comparator is a good solution. You need a reference voltage on the - input. You can do it with a resistive voltage divider.

Comment: The key factor is the pitch of the propeller.

Comment: Thanks, I can use a smaller propeller bit the is a scale model..  trying to make it work with lower rpm.  Thanks for your help.. I was thinking of using a MOSFET?

Comment: MOSFET doesn't work with those voltages either. If you have another power supply you should go with the comparator. If you have enough current(I suppose you get it a.c.) you can raise the voltage with a transformer.